# Can we find which direction we are travelling with respective to the path (Polyline points path)?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, directions, google-polyline

I am implementing **tracking application** using Google maps SDK in IOS 
i want to know whether we can track the user **moving forward or reverse direction** on the **Polyline path** and identify if user travels **reverse direction**

Please provide any valuable suggestions.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GoogleMapsDirection](https://github.com/Djengo/GoogleMapsDirection) to get the path or DirectionResponse from the [Google Directions API.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsResponses)